# Snowflake SQL: Is there a way to select records between 2 years back and the current date?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have seen a lot of questions similar to this but I have yet to see one that goes into detail of how to get records from two years back to today but include the start of the year two years back. Meaning I would like to create a function that will always give me results from January 1st two years back. For this year the results would come from 01-01-2020 to today’s date.

This is what I have so far, but in reality I am using it for a temporary table in my query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM final
WHERE order_date BETWEEN DATEADD(‘year’, -2, current_date) AND current_date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a combination of `DATE_TRUNC` and `DATEADD` to find January 1 of two years ago.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM final
WHERE order_date BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC('year', DATEADD('year', -2, current_date)) AND current_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you had is close. Just truncate the the year.

You can see what happens in isolation:

```
select trunc('2021-03-14 08:24:12'::timestamp, 'YEAR');

-- Output: 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Adding to your SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM final
WHERE order_date 
  BETWEEN trunc(DATEADD(‘year’, -2, current_date), 'YEAR') AND current_date
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to construct **arbitrary** date using [DATE_FROM_PARTS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_from_parts.html):

> Creates a date from individual numeric components that represent the year, month, and day of the month.
>
> ```
> DATE_FROM_PARTS( <year>, <month>, <day> )
> ```

For current_date:

```
SELECT DATE_FROM_PARTS(YEAR(current_date)-2,1,1);
-- 2020-01-01
```

Full query:

```
SELECT *
FROM final
WHERE order_date BETWEEN DATE_FROM_PARTS(YEAR(current_date)-2,1,1) AND current_date
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough

```
where year(current_date)-year(order_date)<=2
```

But in case you have an order_date from the future

```
where year(current_date)-year(order_date)<=2 and order_date<=current_date
```